# Cron jobs trying sends two emails

Tags: linux, cron, postfix-mta

I have a bash script:

```
/usr/bin/certbot renew --apache | gpg -u root -e -s -a -z 9 -r my@email.com | mail -s "Letsencrypt Autorenew" my@email.com
```

I got postfix set up and running fine, sending an email to (changed obviously) my@email.com works.

My problem is that at the end of this script, there is another email stuck in outbox to `root@domain.local`:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Cert not yet due for renewal
```

This only happens to `certbot` command, similar script to send daily logs works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simple redirecting `stderr` (2) to `stdout` (1) solves the issue - `2>&1`:

```
/usr/bin/certbot renew --apache 2>&1 | gpg -u root -e -s -a -z 9 -r my@email.com | mail -s "Letsencrypt Autorenew" my@email.com
```